# Считать значение value поля input js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив элементов input с общим классом.
Надо вывести значение value последнего элемента с этим классом.

```
     messageArray = document.getElementsByClassName('msg_id');
     alert(messageArray[-1].val());
```

Если удобно, подскажите как реализовать с jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
messageArray = document.getElementsByClassName('msg_id');
console.log(messageArray[messageArray.length - 1].value);
```

```html
<input class="msg_id" value="1"/>
<input class="msg_id" value="2"/>
<input class="msg_id" value="3"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

А попробуй document.getElementsByClassName('msg_id:last');

Если как я понял, у тебя список инпутов с одним и тем же классом

Comment: А если сначала подумать?

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).